# Sort array by object property in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

If I have an object as such:

```
class Person {
  var $age;
  function __construct($age) {
    $this->age = $age;
  }
}
```

and I have any array of `Person`s

```
$person1 = new Person(14);
$person2 = new Person(5);
$people = array($person1, $person2);
```

Is there an easy way to sort the `$people` array by the `Person->age` property?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid usort() because it is too expensive of a call as my people array grows. Let's assume I have 15,000 entries in $people.

Comment: What inefficiency do you think usort has that you'll be avoiding by any other method? usort will sort in place and should be pretty efficient.

Comment: It will make a function every call which makes it inefficient in large data sets.

Comment: I've posted some benchmark details - usort isn't too bad, but you can indeed go faster with a non-recursive quicksort.

Comment: What are you doing that you need to sort 15,000 objects at once?

Answer (score 88):

The question was concerned about the inefficiency of using [usort](http://www.php.net/usort) because of the overhead of calling the comparison callback. This answer looks at the difference between using the built-in sort functions and a non-recursive quicksort implementation.

The answer changed over time as PHP evolved since 2009, so I've kept it updated. The older material, while no longer relevant, is still interesting though!

**TL;DR: as of php 7.0.1, a non-recursive quicksort is no longer faster than using usort with a callback.** This wasn't always the case, which is why the details below make interesting reading. The real takeaway is that if you benchmark your problem and try alternative approaches, you can come up with surprising results.

### Jan 2016 update

Well here we are with php 7.0 released and 7.1 on the way! Finally, for this dataset, the built-in usort is *ever-so-slightly* faster!

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Operation | HHVM       | php7.0.1   | php5.6.3   | 5.4.35     | 5.3.29     |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| usort     | *0.0445    | *0.0139    |  0.1503    |  0.1388    |  0.2390    |
| quicksort |  0.0467    |  0.0140    | *0.0912    | *0.1190    | *0.1854    |
|           | 5% slower  | 1% slower  | 40% faster | 15% faster | 23% faster |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

### Jan 2015 update

When I originally answered this in 2009, I compared using usort with a non-recursive quicksort to see if there was a difference. As it turned out, there was *significant* difference, with the quicksort running 3x faster.

As it's now 2015, I thought it might be useful to revisit this, so I took code which sorts 15000 objects using usort and quicksort and ran it on 3v4l.org which runs it on lots of different PHP versions. The full results are here: http://3v4l.org/WsEEQ

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Operation | HHVM       | php7alpha1 | php5.6.3   | 5.4.35     | 5.3.29     |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| usort     | *0.0678    |  0.0438    |  0.0934    |  0.1114    |  0.2330    |
| quicksort |  0.0827    | *0.0310    | *0.0709    | *0.0771    | *0.1412    |
|           | 19% slower | 30% faster | 25% faster | 31% faster | 40% faster |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

### Original Notes from 2009

I tried a [usort](http://www.php.net/usort), and sorted 15000 Person objects in around 1.8 seconds.

As you are concerned about the inefficiency of the calls to the comparison function, I compared it with a non-recursive [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) implementation. This actually ran in around one third of the time, approx 0.5 seconds.

Here's my code which benchmarks the two approaches

```
// Non-recurive Quicksort for an array of Person objects
// adapted from http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Quicksort_non-recursive.php
function quickSort( &$array )
{
 $cur = 1;
 $stack[1]['l'] = 0;
 $stack[1]['r'] = count($array)-1;

 do
 {
  $l = $stack[$cur]['l'];
  $r = $stack[$cur]['r'];
  $cur--;

  do
  {
   $i = $l;
   $j = $r;
   $tmp = $array[(int)( ($l+$r)/2 )];

   // partion the array in two parts.
   // left from $tmp are with smaller values,
   // right from $tmp are with bigger ones
   do
   {
    while( $array[$i]->age < $tmp->age )
     $i++;

    while( $tmp->age < $array[$j]->age )
     $j--;

    // swap elements from the two sides
    if( $i <= $j)
    {
     $w = $array[$i];
     $array[$i] = $array[$j];
     $array[$j] = $w;

     $i++;
     $j--;
    }

   }while( $i <= $j );

 if( $i < $r )
   {
    $cur++;
    $stack[$cur]['l'] = $i;
    $stack[$cur]['r'] = $r;
   }
   $r = $j;

  }while( $l < $r );

 }while( $cur != 0 );


}


// usort() comparison function for Person objects
function personSort( $a, $b ) {
    return $a->age == $b->age ? 0 : ( $a->age > $b->age ) ? 1 : -1;
}


// simple person object    
class Person {
  var $age;
  function __construct($age) {
    $this->age = $age;
  }
}

//---------test internal usort() on 15000 Person objects------

srand(1);
$people=array();
for ($x=0; $x<15000; $x++)
{
     $people[]=new Person(rand(1,100));
}


$start=microtime(true);
usort( $people, 'personSort' );
$total=microtime(true)-$start;

echo "usort took $total\n";


//---------test custom quicksort on 15000 Person objects------

srand(1);
$people=array();
for ($x=0; $x<15000; $x++)
{
     $people[]=new Person(rand(1,100));
}


$start=microtime(true);
quickSort( $people );
$total=microtime(true)-$start;

echo "quickSort took $total\n";
```

An interesting suggestion was to add a `__toString` method to the class and use sort(), so I tried that out too. Trouble is, you must pass SORT_STRING as the second parameter to sort get it to actually call the magic method, which has the side effect of doing a string rather than numeric sort. To counter this, you need to pad the numbers with zeroes to make it sort properly. Net result was that this was slower than both usort and the custom quickSort

```
sort 10000 items took      1.76266698837
usort 10000 items took     1.08757710457
quickSort 10000 items took 0.320873022079
```

Here's the code for the sort() using __toString():

```
$size=10000;

class Person {
  var $age;
  function __construct($age) {
    $this->age = $age;
    $this->sortable=sprintf("%03d", $age);
  }


  public function __toString()
  {
     return $this->sortable;
  }
}

srand(1);
$people=array();
for ($x=0; $x<$size; $x++)
{
     $people[]=new Person(rand(1,100));
}


$start=microtime(true);
sort( $people, SORT_STRING);
$total=microtime(true)-$start;

echo "sort($size) took $total\n"
```

Comment: Did you check that algorithm for correctness? You need to change `$array[$i] < $tmp` by `$array[$i]->age < $tmp->age`, `$tmp < $array[$j]` by `$tmp->age < $array[$j]->age` and `$i->age <= $j->age` by `$i <= $j`.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to compare both algorithms, you should run them on the same data and not just on data of the same size but complete different characteristics. Generate your people array once and sort a copy of that same data with both algorithms.

Comment: What about the remark about testing with the same data? You are still using different test data when comparing the algorithms.

Comment: You also should verify that you get the same results with each function.

Comment: @Gumbo, I seeded the random number generator before each test so that repeated runs of the tests were the same. I added a sanity check to the result too but omitted it from this answer.

Comment: How would you modify the quickSort function to take a second parameter to either sort the array ascending or descending? Also, thanks for this great function. I've definitely made good use of it!

Comment: Geez do while loops.  I forgot those even existed.  Thanks for this function!  I just wish I could understand it enough to reverse its sorting mechanism.  Had to use an array_reverse instead. :)

Comment: Your quickSort function reminds me of my C/C++ classes; very nice.

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer - the community grows via questions and ACCEPTED answers

Comment: As of PHP 8.* the `quicksort` test is once again marginally faster than `usort`.

Answer (score 42):

For that specific scenario, you can sort it using the usort() function, where you define your own function to compare the items in the array.

```
<?php

class Person {
  var $age;
  function __construct($age) {
    $this->age = $age;
  }
}

function personSort( $a, $b ) {
    return $a->age == $b->age ? 0 : ( $a->age > $b->age ) ? 1 : -1;
}

$person1 = new Person(14);
$person2 = new Person(5);
$person3 = new Person(32);
$person4 = new Person(150);
$person5 = new Person(39);
$people = array($person1, $person2, $person3, $person4, $person5);

print_r( $people );

usort( $people, 'personSort' );

print_r( $people );
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid usort() because it is too expensive of a call as my people array grows. Let's assume I have 15,000 entries in $people

Comment: I think you could implement personSort() more simply like this: return $a->age - $b->age;

Comment: hehe, really? i was just so accustomed to doing it like that I didn't really mathematically think it out.

Comment: @DonKirkby `return $a->age - $b->age;` produce wrong results with floating-point numbers, you can use spaceship operator since php 7.0 and it works with floats `return $a->age <=> $b->age;`

Answer (score 11):

You could either use [`usort`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or a [heap](http://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/SplMaxHeap).

```
 class SortPeopleByAge extends SplMaxHeap
  {
      function compare($person1, $person2)
      {
          return $person1->age - $person2->age;
      }
  }

  $people = array(new Person(30), new Person(22), new Person(40));  
  $sorter = new SortPeopleByAge;
  array_map(array($sorter, 'insert'), $people);
  print_r(iterator_to_array($sorter)); // people sorted from 40 to 22
```

Note that the purpose of an Heap is to have an ordered collection at all times and not to replace `usort`. [For large collections (1000+), a heap will be faster and less memory intensive though.](http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/)

An added benefit of having Heaps is being able to use their comparison function for callbacks to other sorting functions, like `usort`. You just have to remember that the order for the comparison is reversed, so any comparison done with a Heap will result in reversed order in `usort`.

```
// using $people array and $sorter
usort($people, array($sorter, 'compare'));
print_r($people); // people sorted from 22 to 40
```

`usort` is fine for small to medium collections where you will do the sorting once at the end. Of course, you dont have to have a heap to use `usort`. You can just as well add any other valid callback for the sorting.

Comment: The most correct answer of all when it comes to big data. Iterators only occupy the memory of the current value per run, while an array occupies the memory with all entries. Iterators in the form of a heap are much more resource-efficient.

Answer (score 9):

I just coded this. It should be faster than `usort` as it does not rely on numerous function calls.

```
function sortByProp($array, $propName, $reverse = false)
{
    $sorted = [];

    foreach ($array as $item)
    {
        $sorted[$item->$propName][] = $item;
    }

    if ($reverse) krsort($sorted); else ksort($sorted);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($sorted as $subArray) foreach ($subArray as $item)
    {
        $result[] = $item;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$sorted = sortByProp($people, 'age');
```

Oh, and it uses `ksort` but it works even if many `$people` are of the same `$age`.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to write a custom comparison function, then use something like [usort](http://uk.php.net/usort) to do the actual sorting. For example, if the member variable was `myVar`, you could sort it as follows:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->myVar == $b->myVar) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->myVar < $b->myVar) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($myArray, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not advice my solution in your example because it would be ugly (And I have not benchmarked it), but it works.... And depending of the need, it may help. :)

```
class Person
{
  public $age;

  function __construct($age)
  {
    $this->age = $age;
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->age;
  }
}

$person1 = new Person(14);
$person2 = new Person(5);

$persons = array($person1, $person2);
asort($persons);
```

Comment: I think the slowness comes from the fact that this still causes a function call per each object, it's just in the class itself now.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability) [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) implementation for values 0...256:

```
function radixsort(&$a)
{
    $n = count($a);
    $partition = array();
    for ($slot = 0; $slot < 256; ++$slot) {
        $partition[] = array();
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
        $partition[$a[$i]->age & 0xFF][] = &$a[$i];
    } 
    $i = 0;
    for ($slot = 0; $slot < 256; ++$slot) {
        for ($j = 0, $n = count($partition[$slot]); $j < $n; ++$j) {
            $a[$i++] = &$partition[$slot][$j];
        }
    }
}
```

This costs only *O*(*n*) since Radix Sort is a non-comparing sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

One observation is that if the source of the data is from a database, it's probably faster to sort using SQL than it would be within PHP.   Of course this is moot if the data source is from a CSV or XML file.

Answer (score 2):

I went with the following approach: created a function that takes an array of objects, then inside the function I create an associative array using the property as key for the array, then sort they array keys using ksort:

```
class Person {
    var $age;
    function __construct($age) {
      $this->age = $age;
    }
}

function sortPerson($persons = Array()){
    foreach($persons as $person){
        $sorted[$person->age] = $person;
    }
    ksort($sorted);
    return array_values($sorted);
}

$person1 = new Person(14);
$person2 = new Person(5);

$persons = array($person1, $person2);
$person = sortPerson($persons);

echo $person[0]->age."\n".$person[1]->age;
/* Output:
5
14
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
$result = Arrays::sort(array($person1, $person2), Comparator::compareBy('age'));
```

http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/comparators.html

Answer (score 1):

`usort()` or `uasort() /* to maintain index association if you were using an associative array */`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you implement [spl ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) in your person object, all the normal php array functions will work properly with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try usort: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Example:

```
<?php
function cmp($obja, $objb)
{
    $a = $obja->sortField;
    $b = $objb->sortField;
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array( /* your objects */ );

usort($a, "cmp");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all member variables in question are guaranteed to be different, it will be simpler and faster to create a new collection indexed by these values and then `ksort` it:

```
 foreach($obj_list as $obj)
    $map[$obj->some_var] = $obj;
 ksort($map);
 /// $map now contains the sorted list
```

If there are duplicate values, you can still avoid `usort` by utilizing a less known feature of `sort` that arrays of arrays are sorted by the value of the first scalar member.

```
 foreach($obj_list as $obj)
    $map[] = array($obj->some_var, $obj);
 sort($map); // sorts $map by the value of ->some_var
```

I guess this still will be 10000000 times faster than `usort`

Comment: 1000 times is a bottomless exaggeration.

Comment: What if the two or more properties of two or more instance are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that takes following things into account:

- namespaces
- private properties
- using getter and setter methods
- property for sort as parameter

**PHP**

```
namespace Dummy;

class Person {

    private $age;

    function __construct($age) {
        $this->setAge($age);
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}

class CustomSort{

    public $field = '';

    public function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a->{'get'.ucfirst($this->field)}(), $b->{'get'.ucfirst($this->field)}());
    }

    public function sortObjectArrayByField($array, $field)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        usort($array, array("Dummy\CustomSort", "cmp"));
        return $array;
    }
}

$robert = new Person(20);
$peter = new Person(12);
$robin = new Person(44);
$people = array($robert, $peter, $robin);

var_dump( $people );

$customSort = new CustomSort();
$people = $customSort->sortObjectArrayByField($people, 'age');

var_dump( $people );
```