# Sorting an array of classes based on a value w/i the class in php?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort array by object property in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462503/sort-array-by-object-property-in-php)

I've got an array of instances of the same class, each contains a variable with a different number. I'd like to sort (ascending) by the number inside of a class, but I don't know of and can't seem to find a decent sort method for something like this... do I need to build a custom function or am I missing a php function that would work in this situation?