# easiest way to sort a php array by property

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I tried some of the methods from this post: [Sort array by object property in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462503/sort-array-by-object-property-in-php)

But I am not able to sort by the last name of my person array in wordpress.

Here is what I do:

```
<?php 
    function personSort( $a, $b ) {
        return $a->last_name == $b->last_name ? 0 : ( $a->last_name > $b->last_name ) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    usort( $autlist, 'personSort' );
    foreach($autlist as $al){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $al->ID; ?>"><?php echo $al->first_name.' '.$al->last_name; ?></option>
```

The order comes out like this:

```
Nick Hammond
Peter Ruck
Nam Ol Lamon
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @skobaljic should I remove the -1?  When I do that the page breaks.

Comment: Nah, that's fine I think, but you are sorting an object, maybe you should use [ArrayObject::uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare strings using the `<` and `>` [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), they are reserved for numbers in PHP. If you do, your strings are transparently type-casted to numbers first, probably all evaluating to `0`, hence the seemingly random result.

Try using [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strcmp.php), which compares strings and returns a number, just like what `usort()` expects:

```
function personSort( $a, $b ) {
    return strcmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);
}
```

Note that starting with PHP 5.3, you can avoid declaring a function in the global scope, and use an anonymous function instead:

```
usort($autlist, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);
});
```